# SwiftUI stops updates during scrolling of List

Tags: swiftui, combine

Given a List in SwiftUI, once panning begins, updating of views in the list seems to pause until the scrolling has been stopped. Is there a way to prevent this?

Consider the following code:

```
class Model: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var offset: CGFloat = 0

    let id = UUID()
    private var timer: Timer!

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.update()
        })
    }

    func update() {
        offset = CGFloat.random(in: 0...300)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model1 = Model()
    @ObservedObject var model2 = Model()
    @ObservedObject var model3 = Model()
    @ObservedObject var model4 = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach([model1, model2, model3, model4]) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: $0.offset, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .animation(.default)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will result in this behaviour:

[image: Video of result]

Comment: i am not sure, but i don't think this is possible with SwiftUI. it might work with UIKit...

Comment: im coming to this, kinda figured while using a custom Activity Indicator.. and it Feels weird as it stops while the user scrolls :/..  to provide a smooth feel... I should keep running while scrolling..... Glad I found this question....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This due to nature of `Timer` and `RunLoop`. Use instead GCD, like in below approach

[image: demo]

```
init() {
    var runner: (() -> ())?
    runner = {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak self] in
            if let self = self {
                self.update()
                runner?()
            }
        }
    }
    runner?()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful thing to know!

Answer (score 16):

You could use GCD as in Asperi's answer, but that doesn't explain why your code didn't work.

The problem is that, while the scroll view is tracking your touch, it runs the run loop in the `.tracking` mode. But because you created your `Timer` using `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`, the `Timer` is only set to run in the `.default` mode.

You could add the timer to all the common run loop modes (which include `.tracking`) like this:

```
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

But I would probably use a Combine publisher instead, like this:

```
class Model: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var offset: CGFloat = 0

    let id = UUID()

    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: RunLoop.main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { _ in CGFloat.random(in: 0...300) }
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.offset = $0 }
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }
}
```